# Преобразование в дату

Tags: access, sql

Доброй ночи, кто подскажет как с использованием ACCESS преобразовать число 1.5 в формат даты? То есть 1.5 - это полтора года. В дальнейшем эту преобразованную дату нужно прибавить к дате нормального вида (01.01.1960) и получить 01.07.1961
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 1 год = 365 дней
2. текущую дату приводим к unixtime
3. прибавляем кол-во дней (   1,5 * 365 )
4. переводим unixtime в текущую дату

Answer (score 1):

Есть функция dateadd. Приращение должно быть целым, поэтому использовать можно месяцы:
    DateAdd("m",18,[дата])